# Jersey - How to use @Context annotation outside of a servlet?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am trying to set up a Jersey ClientResponseFilter. It is working fine, but I want to deserialize my request parameters into a String so I can write helpful messages into a log file containing the actual data.

I was thinking about using MessageBodyWorkers for this. As this link below says:
"In case you need to directly work with JAX-RS entity providers, for example to serialize an entity in your resource method, filter or in a composite entity provider, you would need to perform quite a lot of steps."

Source: [7.4. Jersey MessageBodyWorkers API](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/message-body-workers.html#d0e6219)

This is exactly what I want to prevent.

So I was thinking about injecting the messagebodyworkers into my filter like this:

```java
package somepackage.client.response;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientResponseFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.glassfish.jersey.message.MessageBodyWorkers;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

@Provider
public class ResponseFilter implements ClientResponseFilter {

    // TODO: these workers are not injected
    @Context
    private MessageBodyWorkers workers;
    private final Logger logger;

    public ResponseFilter(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext, ClientResponseContext responseContext)
            throws IOException {
        if (responseValid(responseContext)) {
            return;
        }
        logger.error("Error", "Some param");
    }

    private boolean responseValid(ClientResponseContext responseContext) {
        if (responseContext.getStatus() == HttpServletResponse.SC_OK) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

But the reference is always null and remains null. Note that this filter is running in a standalone application, no servlet container is available.

Why isn't the annotation working in this case? How can I make it work? Or if making this approach to work is impossible, how can I work around this?

Any suggestions?

Comment: 'Note that this filter is running in a standalone application, no servlet container is available.' Why? You need somebody who does the injecting.

Comment: @Tichodroma: thank you for taking your time to reply. This is what I also suspected. So is there a way to workaround this? I saw that there is something called AbstractBinder in Glassfish HK2 and the Jersey "@InjectParam" annotation says "When Jersey is used without IoC component provider support this annotation provides basic injection support of beans. References to beans may be obtained be they existing references to instances of resources or just beans that have JAX-RS/Jersey artifacts injected on them." But I am not sure how shall I make this work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Here is the workaround solution for the problem above: we should use @Inject and the HK2 Dependency Injection Kernel

[HK2 Dependency Injection Kernel Link](https://hk2.java.net/2.3.0-b09/)

First we need to make some changes to the filter:

```
package somepackage.client.response;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientResponseFilter;

import org.glassfish.jersey.message.MessageBodyWorkers;
import org.slf4j.Logger;

public class ResponseFilter implements ClientResponseFilter {

    @Inject
    private MessageBodyWorkers workers;
    private Logger logger;

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext, ClientResponseContext responseContext)
            throws IOException {
        if (responseValid(responseContext)) {
            return;
        }
        logger.error("Error", "Some param");
    }

    private boolean responseValid(ClientResponseContext responseContext) {
        if (responseContext.getStatus() == HttpServletResponse.SC_OK) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setLogger(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

}
```

As you can see the constructor changed, the class uses the default constructor, and the annotation changed to @Inject. Be aware that there are two @Inject annotations with the same name. Make sure you use: javax.inject.Inject.

Then we need to implement org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder:

```
package somepackage.client;

import org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.binding.AbstractBinder;
import org.glassfish.jersey.message.MessageBodyWorkers;
import org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory;

public class Binder extends AbstractBinder {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(MessageBodyFactory.class).to(MessageBodyWorkers.class);
    }

}
```

And finally we should register the filter and our binder in the client:

```
...
        client.register(ResponseFilter.class);
        client.register(new SitemapBinder());
...
```

Then the worker is going to be injected fine.